# Finagle resolver example

Tags: scala, finagle

I've been looking Tweeter finagle technology, and I'm looking forward to see how Resolver it's applyied https://twitter.github.io/finagle/docs/com/twitter/finagle/Resolver.html

Can anybody please point me to a blog/github project with examples of an practicle implementation?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zk2Resolver](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/develop/finagle-serversets/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/serverset2/Zk2Resolver.scala#L57) in the finagle project is a production-quality resolver.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look